# No cargan las páginas de mi web

Tags: php

Tengo problemas con mi web, ya no me carga nada más que el *home*, y las otras páginas no se visualizan, solo me sale este código de error:

> Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/estudioo/public_html/administrator/inc/clsContenidoEst.php on line 107

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código, por favor?

Comment: este es el mensaje que me saleCall to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/estudioo/public_html/administrator/inc/clsContenidoEst.php on line 107

Comment: Me refiero a que pongas el código de la línea 105 a la línea 110 para saber por que se origina y salta el error que presentas arriba.

Comment: si te refieres a la linea, me sale que es 107

Comment: Por eso, queremos saber que contiene esa línea XD

Comment: ese es todo el dato que tengo, la web no la administro yo, soy cliente y la empresa que esta viendo eso se demora mucho en resolverlo, por eso quiero saber mas sobre el tema, gracias

Comment: Realmente no podemos ayudarte a encontrar el error si no sabemos que es lo que contiene esa linea. Podrías pedirle esa información a la empresa, y con gusto les ayudaremos a resolverla a la brevedad posible :)

Comment: entiendo, justamente ellos se están demorando en ver la solución así que dudo que puedan responderme rápidamente. Otra consulta, este tipo de error a que se debe? es problema del servidor? de la estructura donde se diseñó la web? una persona con accesos a administrador de contenidos pudo haber tenido una mala manipulación?

Comment: me agrada tu actitud @César tienes lo que se necesita para ser bueno en el desarrollo de software: ser curioso y preguntarte de manera constante, esto te empuja a buscar respuestas, ergo, te vuelves autodidacta :D bienvenido a la familia de SOes, esperamos verte colaborando con el sitio :D saludos

Comment: El problema es básicamente que se está haciendo una consulta a base de datos que bien tiene un error, o bien está devolviendo `null`, al intentar  extraer los datos de esa respuesta, que no se trata de un conjunto de resultados válido, se dispara este error.

Comment: Creo que si colocas codigo en tu pregunta y especificas donde esta el error te ayudaremos con gusto de resto solo con un mensaje no sabriamos que produce dicho error dentro de tu condigo php

Answer (score 1):

Con la poca información que aportas, me atrevería a apostar a que estás consultado una base de datos y no estás comprobando si la consulta tuvo éxito por lo que intentas hacer el `fetch_array()` sobre un objeto no válido.

Supongo que tienes algo así:

```
    <?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mi_db");

$resultado =$conexion->query("SELECT campo1,campo2,campo3 FROM tabla WHERE loquesea");  

$row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); <-- Aquí te da el fallo.
?>
```

Para evitar estos problemas, asegúrate siempre de que las operaciones tengan éxito. Te copio y pego el ejemplo del manual oficial:

```
<?php
// Vamos a pasar una variable $_GET a nuestro ejemplo, en este caso es
// 'aid' para 'actor_id' de nuestra base de datos Sakila. Le vamos a asignar un
// valor predeterminado de 1, y a amoldarla a un integer para evitar inyecciones
// de SQL y/o problemas de seguridad relacionados. El manejo de todo esto va más
// allá del alcance de este sencillo ejemplo:
//   http://example.org/script.php?aid=42
if (isset($_GET['aid']) && is_numeric($_GET['aid'])) {
    $aid = (int) $_GET['aid'];
} else {
    $aid = 1;
}

// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada sakila
// Nombre de host: 127.0.0.1, nombre de usuario: tu_usuario, contraseña: tu_contraseña, bd: sakila
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

// ¡Oh, no! Existe un error 'connect_errno', fallando así el intento de conexión
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    // La conexión falló. ¿Que vamos a hacer? 
    // Se podría contactar con uno mismo (¿email?), registrar el error, mostrar una bonita página, etc.
    // No se debe revelar información delicada

    // Probemos esto:
    echo "Lo sentimos, este sitio web está experimentando problemas.";

    // Algo que no se debería de hacer en un sitio público, aunque este ejemplo lo mostrará
    // de todas formas, es imprimir información relacionada con errores de MySQL -- se podría registrar
    echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";

    // Podría ser conveniente mostrar algo interesante, aunque nosotros simplemente saldremos
    exit;
}

// Realizar una consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name FROM actor WHERE actor_id = $aid";
if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    // ¡Oh, no! La consulta falló. 
    echo "Lo sentimos, este sitio web está experimentando problemas.";

    // De nuevo, no hacer esto en un sitio público, aunque nosotros mostraremos
    // cómo obtener información del error
    echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
    echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

// ¡Uf, lo conseguimos!. Sabemos que nuestra conexión a MySQL y nuestra consulta
// tuvieron éxito, pero ¿tenemos un resultado?
if ($resultado->num_rows === 0) {
    // ¡Oh, no ha filas! Unas veces es lo previsto, pero otras
    // no. Nosotros decidimos. En este caso, ¿podría haber sido
    // actor_id demasiado grande? 
    echo "Lo sentimos. No se pudo encontrar una coincidencia para el ID $aid. Inténtelo de nuevo.";
    exit;
}

// Ahora, sabemos que existe solamente un único resultado en este ejemplo, por lo
// que vamos a colocarlo en un array asociativo donde las claves del mismo son los
// nombres de las columnas de la tabla
$actor = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "A veces veo a " . $actor['first_name'] . " " . $actor['last_name'] . " en la TV.";

// Ahora, vamor a obtener cinco actores aleatorios y a imprimir sus nombres en una lista.
// El manejo de errores va a ser menor aquí, aunque ya sabemos como hacerlo
$sql = "SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name FROM actor ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Lo sentimos, este sitio web está experimentando problemas.";
    exit;
}

// Imprimir nuestros cinco actores aleatorios en una lista, y enlazar cada uno
echo "<ul>\n";
while ($actor = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li><a href='" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "?aid=" . $actor['actor_id'] . "'>\n";
    echo $actor['first_name'] . ' ' . $actor['last_name'];
    echo "</a></li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";

// El script automáticamente liberará el resultado y cerrará la conexión
// a MySQL cuando finalice, aunque aquí lo vamos a hacer nostros mismos
$resultado->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Probablemente comprobando si tuvo éxito la consulta, o la conexión conozcas porque falla y soluciones el problema. De no ser este tu problema, como te indican en los comentarios, adjunta el código en cuestión.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?